# DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties

Tags: android, gradle, google-vision

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties
>       File1: C:\Users\venka.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-vision\0.17.2-beta\2b8e0731b29035e73cd4e5d40cf993ec912f2913\google-cloud-vision-0.17.2-beta.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\venka.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-core\1.0.1\2b85bbbee4913a5fed34359d148c405dd8c98aac\google-cloud-core-1.0.1.jar

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Comment: In your build.gradle you have two entries google-cloud-core-1.0.1 and google-cloud-vision-0.17.2-beta. Remove which is unnecessary.